# 2 iPhones with iMessage and getting messages from one phone to the other

Tags: iphone, sms

I have a personal iPhone XR. A couple of weeks ago my boss wanted to get business cells for a few of us (I'm a customer facing landscape designer) so we could ignore work calls when we wanted to.  As a Mac/apple user for years but I'm no power user or anything, we selected 2020 iPhone SE.

- I want to push my personal texts through to my work phone so that during the day I can set my personal phone aside and not worry about it.
- I have both devices signed in to the same Apple ID and I think I set
  it up right.
- Some things push through and some things don't.

Mostly what I've missed is group texts that include android users. At first I thought it was because it's only pushing iMessages through and not true SMS, but I miss texts from some android users but not all. Also I get regular SMS pushed through to my laptop and iPad....so that doesn't seem to line up.

[image: This is the messages settings "send and receive" page from the work SE. The "402-8..." number is my personal and the other is the work number.]

Is there a general fix for having two phones, and allowing the personal one to forward everything to the work phone and being able to switch that on and off cleanly once a day?

Answer (score 0):

SMS does not do group messages (well it might be up to the provider)

In the UK the phone providers will charge extra for MMS which do do group messages but not directly supported by Messages by default.

This is one reason to use WhatsApp, Signal etc.